# How to dynamically resize a cached threadpool in java

Tags: java, multithreading, customization, executors

I'm doing asynchronous threading using futures in my work at the moment. I want its functionality to be similar to a 'cachedThreadPool' but also to do these two things:

1. Increment the maximum number of threads allowed each time a thread successfully completes.
2. Decrement the maximum number of threads allowed if a thread throws an exception or timeouts.

Is this possible to do in a custom `ThreadPoolExecutor`? I am new to using Executors in this way so pointing me in the right direction would be very helpful towards solving this.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#setMaximumPoolSize(int) ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply,  I am aware of that method but what I need to know  where exactly I have to call it from? Like in the case of a thread throwing an exception how can I retrieve the current maximum amount from my custom class and increment it?

Comment: There's a getMaximumPoolSize() method. And you can handle uncaught exceptions from threadpool by overriding the afterExecute method.

Comment: Sorry to double post but basically, how will the custom threadpool know if an exception was thrown in one of its threads?

Comment: An exception occurring _in_ one of the threads would have no bearing on the size of the thread pool. The issue being recommended here is handling the dispersing of a thread when the pool is empty.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to increase the threadpool size?  Items will queue until a thread is available.  If this is because you plan on spawning child threads and adding them to the pool, you may want to use a [`ForkJoinPool`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html) which is new to Java 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dynamically resizing thread pools should be considered carefully. If you have timeouts and your response is to reduce the number of threads, assuming the task is parrelizable, it will likely make the problem worse.

Anyway, here's code that changes the size of the pool when a task throws an exception and makes it larger if a task completes succesfully

```
class ManagedThreadPoolExecutor extends ThreadPoolExecutor {
      @Override
      protected void afterExecute(Runnable r, Throwable t) {
           if(t != null)
                setMaximumPoolSize(getMaximumPoolSize()-1);
           else
                setMaximumPoolSize(getMaximumPoolSize()+1);

      }
}
```

Comment: That code will decrement the pool size, but won't actually set the size correctly. `getMaximumPoolSize()--` returns the original count before decrementing. Should probably use `--getMaximumPoolSize()` and `++getMaximimumPoolSize()` instead

Comment: @RyanJ I made it slightly more obvious given that this confused me.

Comment: Noted, I'm really just experimenting here at the moment. I'll give Powerlord's suggestion a try as well. I'm feeling really silly here as I missed their was a throwable parameter in the afterExecute method.